# Project Euler 76 - List All Partitions For a Given Number

Tags: .net, vb.net, numbers

Here is how [Project Euler Problem #76](http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=76) sounds like:
"How many different ways can one hundred be written as a sum of at least two positive integers?"

I've struggled to get it right for a couple of days, tried to solve in different ways and got mostly the same results for small numbers (those that are easy to check). I ended up with an algorithm that lists all partitions for a given number in alphabetical order, descending (starting from "N-1 + 1"). Written in VB.NET:

```
Dim ub As Integer = 6
Dim wayCount As Integer = 0
For n = ub - 1 To 1 Step -1
  'init value array (first combination)
  Dim s As New List(Of Integer)
  For m = 1 To ub \ n : s.Add(n) : Next
  Dim b As Integer = ub Mod n
  If b <> 0 Then s.Add(b)

  'from where to start decrementing
  Dim k As Integer = s.Count - 1
  While k > 0 And s(k) = 1 : k -= 1 : End While

  Do
    wayCount += 1 : Console.WriteLine(String.Join(" + ", s) & " = " & s.Sum)
    If s(k) = 1 Then k -= 1
    If k = -1 Then Exit Do
    s(k) -= 1
    s.Add(1)
  Loop While k >= 1
Next

Console.WriteLine("count=" & wayCount)
```

The code works for numbers 1-6 inclusive and starts failing for N=7, with 1 combination missed. For N=8 it misses 2 (19 instead of 21). For N=100 the answer is 4576, which is several orders of magnitude less than required. Clearly, I am missing some very important detail.

If you don't have time or means to compile and run the above code, here is the output (N=7):

```
6 + 1 = 7
5 + 2 = 7
5 + 1 + 1 = 7
4 + 3 = 7
4 + 2 + 1 = 7
4 + 1 + 1 + 1 = 7
3 + 3 + 1 = 7
3 + 2 + 1 + 1 = 7
3 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 = 7
2 + 2 + 2 + 1 = 7
2 + 2 + 1 + 1 + 1 = 7
2 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 = 7
1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 = 7
count=13
```

I've studied these links:

[(ProjectEuler) Sum Combinations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/438540/projecteuler-sum-combinations) - provides a mathematical solution, which does not list all combinations

[Generating the partitions of a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400794/generating-the-partitions-of-a-number) - is in python, which I cannot read/run/understand.

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Isn't the point of P Euler self gratification? It seems many people want these solved for them, which seems antithetical to their purpose. Additionally, this isn't really a vb/vb.net/.net issue - the methodology (only) is the relevant tag

Comment: I don't see that the OP want code without individual initiative. I can neither agree with your second point, he needs a working solution in VB.NET and thats what tags are supposed to.

Comment: Thanks, Tim. I would appreciate if you at least provided the partition #14, which is supposedly missing when N=7. The code prints everything to the screen and with all my (bad) luck I can't find the missing combination.

Comment: @Kevin: there is a much easier way to get a solved status on any PE problem, by using Google search. I would not be here if I just wanted the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As promised, here is some code that does partitioning of N (stored in ub) using natural numbers up to N, but not including it. With slight modification, it should be able to partition by any function, including that with floating point output.

Basic idea is that for every value used in partitioning we are using coefficient bucket, which is a multiplier of that value. On every step we either charge the value to maximum available, move left or right, decrement current multiplier and test if we get to the sum. Once sum was successfully partitioned, wayCount is incremented and result is printed to the screen.

This might be a somewhat dirty implementation, but it works in a reasonable time even for the scope of the problem in question (under 5 minutes on my machine), generating several millions of partitions per second. Healthy criticism is always welcome!

```
Dim ub As Integer = 10
Dim availableIncrements(ub - 2) As Integer
Dim weightCoefficients(ub - 2) As Integer
For i = 0 To ub - 2
  availableIncrements(i) = ub - i - 1
  weightCoefficients(i) = -1 'indicates that enumeration has not started yet
Next
Dim wayCount As Integer = 0

Dim pos, sum As Integer
pos = 0 : sum = 0
Do
  If weightCoefficients(pos) = -1 Then
    'when we came here first, charge coefficient to maximum available
    weightCoefficients(pos) = (ub - sum) \ availableIncrements(pos)
  ElseIf weightCoefficients(pos) > 0 Then
    'regular cycle: decrease by one
    weightCoefficients(pos) -= 1
  Else
    'return to previous bucket
    If pos = 0 Then Exit Do
    pos -= 1
    Continue Do
  End If

  'calculate current sum
  sum = 0
  For k = 0 To pos
    sum += availableIncrements(k) * weightCoefficients(k)
  Next
  'found combination
  If sum = ub And weightCoefficients(pos) > 0 Then
    wayCount += 1

    'printing to screen, remove when expecting many combinations
    Dim printList As New List(Of Integer)
    For i = 0 To pos 'which number to print
      For k = 1 To weightCoefficients(i) 'how many times to print a number
        printList.Add(availableIncrements(i))
      Next
    Next
    Console.WriteLine(String.Join(" + ", printList))

    'if we were in the last bucket and we just partitioned the number,
    'no need to go down and check all lower coefficients, instead move one column back.
    If pos = UBound(availableIncrements) Then
      pos -= 1
      Continue Do
    End If
  End If

  If pos < UBound(availableIncrements) Then
    pos += 1
    weightCoefficients(pos) = -1 'prepare to charge
  End If

  'this is something to keep you busy (so you know it's not hanging)
  'uncomment for long enumerations
  'If wayCount Mod 100000 = 0 Then Console.WriteLine(wayCount)
Loop

Console.WriteLine("count=" & wayCount)
```

Answer (score 3):

You say, "The code works for numbers 1-6 inclusive and starts failing for N=7, with 1 combination missed."  You should step through your code one line at a time for N=7, either in a debugger or by hand.  By seeing in detail exactly what your code is doing you will be able to see where it misses a combination.

Comment: I did both, and because it shows everything on screen, I really can't think of any partition #14 that's missing from the list (for N=7).

Comment: To find all the partitions of seven, you need to look at ways to combine with the partitions of 1 to 6 you have already found.  Be careful to avoid double counting.

Comment: I updated the first post to include output for N=7, have you looked at it?

Comment: Yep, you are right, it's the one. This is what happens when you spend too much with your own code. :) Thanks for a hint, I'll keep looking for a way to improve the algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

There is a fairly accurate closed-form solution to this problem, believe it or not.

Hardy and Ramanujan's formula:

```
                    e^(PI sqrt(2n/3))
            p(n) ~   -----------------
                        4n sqrt(3)
```

which gets closer as n->infinity.
The mathematician Rademacher made an exact formula, but it isn't pretty.
[Here's a discussion.](http://users.math.yale.edu/~alf8/Folsom-Masri-MathAnn07-10.pdf)

I would recommend reading about it on Wikipedia and Mathworld [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartitionFunctionP.html) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29#Partition_function).

[This](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/47611/exact-formulas-for-the-partition-function) is the MathOverflow discussion of the problem.

I'm not saying these are the best solutions to this problem. In fact for reasonably small values of n they're a waste of time, but it is interesting to see this solution as well as the more "computer-oriented" ones.

Comment: Thanks for providing valuable links. However, this question is concerned about listing these partitions, rather than finding partition count.

With proper implementation, such algorithm would be able to list not just natural partitions, but also prime partitions, by polygonal numbers, floating point, proper fraction or in fact any functional values. A side problem it would also solve sounds like 'Find 100000th lexicographical partition of N=100'.

Actually, I already have working version of the code, which I am going to post later this day.

Comment: My bad then. I thought you just needed the quantity of partitions.

Comment: There is a very good Youtube lecture on this topic ( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aj4FozCSg8g ) , given by mathematician Ken Ono, who is a world specialist on this topic. He mentions all these formulas plus explains what Ramanujan figured out.